# Monday count only

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I just want to count the dates Monday of each number in column C filtered by column A. But it is giving an error in the formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL (JANEIRO!C2, "1"; FEVEREIRO!C2, "1 ")
```

[drive link here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W3_OXuu2LYKMJZA_ET_A9nivDCRW1xv-pSsUINVCh6c)

Comment: For each sheet, create column D, insert `=if(weekday(C2,2)<>1,0,weekday(C2,2))` in Cell D2 and copy to bottom of content. Count = `=COUNTIF(JANEIRO!$A$2:$A$30,"=1")+COUNTIF(FEVEREIRO!$A$2:$A$32,"=1")`

Comment: unfortunately did not work, is giving error in the 2 functions informed

Comment: 1) You have data validation set on the new column D; turn that off. 2) Regional settings "may" require a semi-colon instead of a comma in "weekday". For example `weekday(C2;2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **A2** cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(""&TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY({JANEIRO!A$2:C; FEVEREIRO!A$2:C}; 
 "select Col1 where dayOfWeek(Col3) = 2"; 0); ",")); "^"&TO_TEXT(A2)&"$"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_-LckMTWZXtQrrjpTfzx9zCyeuszTlh9pONeKWOFOI/edit#gid=483099806)

Comment: I did the procedure. But Unfortunately, the B column count of cell B5 is wrong. The number 4 only appears 2 times on Monday. Using the formula = ARRAYFORMULA (SUM (N (REGEXMATCH (QUERY ({JANUARY! A $ 2: C; FEBRUARY! A $ 2: C};
  "select Col1 where dayOfWeek (Col3) = 2"; 0); "" & A5)))) appeared 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

there are no mondays. formula is:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({JANEIRO!C2:C; FEVEREIRO!C2:C}; 
 "where dayOfWeek(Col1) = 2"; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I understand, I already made change in column C date and includes the dates of Monday. But, I want you to count Monday as follows: = sort (unique (transpose (split (join (","; JANUARY! $ A $ 2: $ A $ 197; FEBRUARY! $ A $ 2: $ A $ 197); " Is "))); 1; TRUE) possible?

Comment: @Glaucco You didn’t mention this in your question; it’s not even a variation on what player0 covered in their answer; the data ranges don’t match anything in your spreadsheet. Why not open this as a new question and explain EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve. You should also include an example of a successful outcome in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I just want to count the dates Monday of each column C number filtered by column A. I made change to the spreadsheet by including an EXPECTED RESULT sheet for ease of understanding. Please see the change at the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W3_OXuu2LYKMJZA_ET_A9nivDCRW1xv-pSsUINVCh6c/edit#gid=483099806